# How do I nest blocks so they end at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

How would I turn this method into a block that won't complete until the 'request startWithCompletionHandler' block completes it's request and the code in its own block?

I have a series of blocks that I need to call in order but they all require code to sent up their requests. Trying to find a clean way to accomplish the task.

```
+(void)???????? ^block()
{
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:kFacebookQueryMeKey];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        ....
    }];
}
```

ADDED INFO: yes, I want the outer function to wait until the inner function is complete

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you mean.  Given your example code, it seems like you want your function to call a block when the nested block completes.  So you'd want something like this:

```
+ (void)doMyThingWithBlock:(void(^)(void))block
{
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:kFacebookQueryMeKey];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        // do whatever you want with the connection ...

        if (block) block();

    }];
}
```

On the other hand, maybe you want the outer function to wait for the nested block to complete before it returns.  In that case, it's a bit more complicated.  You need to use a lock to wait for the block to complete, like this:

```
#define kMyThingNotDone 0
#define kMyThingDone    1

+ (void)doMyThingAndWait
{
    NSConditionLock *lock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:kMyThingNotDone];

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:kFacebookQueryMeKey];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        // do whatever you want with the connection ...

        [lock lock];
        [lock unlockWithCondition:kMyThingDone];

    }];

    [lock lockWhenCondition:kMyThingDone];
    [lock unlock];
}
```

Be warned - you don't want to do this on the main thread, or you'll lock up the user interface.  You also have to be sure that the request isn't going wait for anything to happen on the thread you call this from, otherwise you'll end up with a deadlock.

Answer (score -1):

If your only requirement is that the request be executed in order and FBRequest does not do it for you (I'm not familiar with the API), one option is to wrap those calls in a serial queue.

```
dispatch_queue_t mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.serializedrequests", NULL);
dispatch_async(mySerialQueue, ^{
   FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:kFacebookQueryMeKey];
   [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    ....
   }];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

With API like facebook, you never know upfront how long a request will take (changes in the network conditions / load on their ends / ....) so I wouldn't use any thread locking / waiting with it.

If you pass to your method a block (which can encapsulate other blocks as well to be executed sequentially) :

```
+(void) getFacebookDataWithCompletion:(void (^)(<some parameters))completion {

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:kFacebookQueryMeKey];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

       if (!error)
       {
           //Do your thing with the facebook result (update user info, ....)
       }
       if (completion)
       {
           //Now that you have what you need from fb run your block(s) 
           completion(<params>);
       }

    }];
  }
```